# org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalException: Failed to load from file, META-INF/ServiceData.xml

Tags: web-services, exception, apache-axis, meta-inf

I have the same problem as [laalto - Axis2 error while running web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118966/axis2-error-while-running-web-service/24239919#24239919).

The following exception occurs when I call the webservice, although the service seems to run properly:

```
06-16@11:46:05 DEBUG DataRetrievalUtil - File does not exist in the Service Repository! File=META-INF/ServiceData.xml [http-bio-8080-exec-9]
    06-16@11:46:05 DEBUG AxisDataLocatorImpl - Check loading failure for file, META-INF/ServiceData.xml.Message = Failed to load from file, META-INF/ServiceData.xml [http-bio-8080-exec-9]
    06-16@11:46:05 DEBUG AxisDataLocatorImpl - Check loading failure for file, META-INF/ServiceData.xml [http-bio-8080-exec-9]
    org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalException: Failed to load from file, META-INF/ServiceData.xml
            at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalUtil.buildOM(DataRetrievalUtil.java:64)
            at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.loadServiceData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:104)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getDefaultDataLocator(AxisService.java:2949)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getDataLocator(AxisService.java:2933)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2850)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1545)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: File does not exist in the Service Repository! File=META-INF/ServiceData.xml
            at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalUtil.getInputStream(DataRetrievalUtil.java:103)
            at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalUtil.buildOM(DataRetrievalUtil.java:60)
            ... 26 more
```

My webservice project is about two years old and its structure has never changed since than. The structure is:

```
Webservices.war|-----axis2-web
               |-----META-INF|
                             |------MANIFEST.MF
               |-----WEB-INF |
                             |------web.xml
                             |------sources.....
```

And there has never been a file called "ServiceData.xml".

I use Tomcat 7.0_39 with Axis2 1.5.6. The webservice component was implemented with Java 1.7.0_21.

Is it possible that this error previously appeared without have been logged yet? -I changed the logging behaviour of the webservices with the last deployment.

I found some hints to rename the "services.xml" to "ServiceData.xml", but is this really a proper solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution worked for me:**

The exception seems to have no impact since there is the services.xml in folder

```
webapps/WebServices/WEB-INF/services/WebService/META-INF
```

Therefore one can ignore this exception. Nevertheless an exception always indicates an error and therefore it should be solved.

I found a solution, which is not satifying but prevents the exception from occurring:

Copy the **services.xml** in the folder above and rename it to **ServiceData.xml**. The exception will never occur! To simply place an empty file named **ServiceData.xml** does not work! The **ServiceData.xml** must contain the same information as the file **services.xml**!

This is unfortunately a practical, but not a good solution, because it fixes not the cause of this exception but the impact.

If there is a better solution please contribute here!